# using ATL component in Delphi

Tags: delphi, com, atl

[rewritten to be more comprehensible]

I am lost trying to use a COM object in Delphi. The object was created using Visual Studio ATL.

I have tested the object in VBScript:

```
Set ourObj = Server.CreateObject( "JC_ATL_Q.JCsimple")
ourJCversion = ourObj.JCversion
Response.Write "<li>Get: JCversion = " + cstr( ourJCversion)
```

In Delphi, I followed:

> http://101.lv/learn/delphi/ch15.htm1

to create the code below, but this produces the error

"The specified procedure could not be found"

I have checked the registry and the TGUIDs seem to be correct.

Am I doing the correct thing to access an IDispatch interface? Is there a way of getting further information as to what is going wrong?

```
IJCsimple = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{96154141-4169-4321-BADC-A08F1B2D53A4}']
    function get_JCversion: Integer; stdcall;
  end;

const
CLASS_JCsimple: TGUID = '{6724FCDA-14F6-4D40-82A1-C8FD451BED9C}';

var
  Form2: TForm2;
  Result : variant;

implementation

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin

    Result := CreateComObject(CLASS_JCsimple) as IJCsimple;

  end;

end.
```

***Solution:***
As Remy Lebeau points out, I should not be reinventing the wheel, but should use the Component >> Import Component >> Import Type Library tool

Comment: What is your specific question.

Comment: Trying to access the property "Version" causes an Exception. Can anyone help get this sorted?

Comment: But what is your question? What specific detail in the text do you want us to address. "Can anyone help" isn't a valid question here.

Comment: Funny that you mention an exception twice in you question and once more in the comments, but you never say what the exception message is! Maybe you havn't read it or maybe you think it is irrelevant to the problem you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong declaration for your interface method.  It should look more like this:

```
type
  IJCsimple = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{DA13AEFD-C5A1-4A94-AD74-B9C355E1F19C}']
    function get_Version(out Result: Integer): HResult; stdcall;
    property Version: Integer read get_Version;
  end;
```

Or this:

```
type
  IJCsimple = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{DA13AEFD-C5A1-4A94-AD74-B9C355E1F19C}']
    function Version: Integer; safecall;
  end;
```

That being said, you should not be implementing the interface unit manually to begin with.  The correct solution is to have the IDE import the COM object's TypeLibrary and generate proper wrapper code for you:

[Importing Type Library Information](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Importing_Type_Library_Information)